# Delphi 11.1 Fastreports / TeeChart issue

Tags: teechart, fastreport, delphi-11-alexandria

I have created an app for users to create reports in FastReports with charts.  The standalone exe works fine.  However when I incorporate the same code in a DLL, adding or editing a chart generates the following error:

```
exception message  : Access violation at address 092E95C7 in module 'NEWREPORTDLL.DLL'. Write of address 00000000.

main thread ($5c54):
092e95c7 +007 NEWREPORTDLL.DLL System             18097   +5 TObject.InitInstance
096bcdc4 +010 NEWREPORTDLL.DLL Winapi.GDIPAPI      7277   +1 TGdiplusBase.NewInstance
092e9ba3 +007 NEWREPORTDLL.DLL System             19251   +5 @ClassCreate
096d0df6 +00e NEWREPORTDLL.DLL Winapi.GDIPOBJ      4497   +0 TGPGraphics.Create
09b9088c +010 NEWREPORTDLL.DLL VCLTee.TeeGDIPlus   1274   +1 TGDIPlusCanvas.RecreateGraphics
09b909a8 +048 NEWREPORTDLL.DLL VCLTee.TeeGDIPlus   1305   +6 TGDIPlusCanvas.GetGraphics
09b90dee +0d6 NEWREPORTDLL.DLL VCLTee.TeeGDIPlus   1468  +20 CheckGraphics
09b90ea6 +0ae NEWREPORTDLL.DLL VCLTee.TeeGDIPlus   1504  +31 TGDIPlusCanvas.InitWindow
09af5050 +0a8 NEWREPORTDLL.DLL VCLTee.TeeProcs     2243  +12 InnerDraw
09af517c +010 NEWREPORTDLL.DLL VCLTee.TeeProcs     2279   +7 TCustomTeePanel.Draw
09af64f6 +0ae NEWREPORTDLL.DLL VCLTee.TeeProcs     3322  +19 TCustomTeePanel.NonBufferDraw
09af61c9 +02d NEWREPORTDLL.DLL VCLTee.TeeProcs     3209   +3 TCustomTeePanel.DrawToMetaCanvas
09ba996f +1a3 NEWREPORTDLL.DLL frxChart            1032  +26 TfrxChartView.Draw
0978e70c +044 NEWREPORTDLL.DLL frxClass           12836   +2 TfrxReportComponent.InteractiveDraw
```

Attempting to add a series results in this:

```
exception message  : Access violation at address 092E95C7 in module 'NEWREPORTDLL.DLL'. Write of address 00000000.

main thread ($5c54):
092e95c7 +007 NEWREPORTDLL.DLL System                     18097   +5 TObject.InitInstance
096bcdc4 +010 NEWREPORTDLL.DLL Winapi.GDIPAPI              7277   +1 TGdiplusBase.NewInstance
092e9ba3 +007 NEWREPORTDLL.DLL System                     19251   +5 @ClassCreate
096d3c88 +010 NEWREPORTDLL.DLL Winapi.GDIPOBJ              6665   +0 TGPFont.Create
09b91f62 +23a NEWREPORTDLL.DLL VCLTee.TeeGDIPlus           2020  +53 TGDIPlusCanvas.DoChangedFont
09ad1958 +070 NEWREPORTDLL.DLL VCLTee.TeCanvas             5547  +19 TTeeCanvas.AssignFontSize
09ad198c +018 NEWREPORTDLL.DLL VCLTee.TeCanvas             5552   +1 TTeeCanvas.AssignFont
09af54c9 +025 NEWREPORTDLL.DLL VCLTee.TeeProcs             2616   +4 TCustomTeePanel.TryAssignFont
09b99697 +07b NEWREPORTDLL.DLL VCLTee.TeeGalleryPanel       695   +8 TGalleryChart.SetTitleFontSize
```

DLL Project source is this:

```
library NewReportDLL;

uses
  ShareMem,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  Winapi.Windows,
  Winapi.Messages,
  System.Variants,
  System.IOUtils,
  Vcl.Graphics,
  VCL.Themes,
  Vcl.Controls,
  Vcl.Forms,
  Vcl.Dialogs,
  uGlobals in 'uGlobals.pas',
  uDMRPT in 'uDMRPT.pas' {DMRPT: TDataModule},
  ufrmRptTest in 'ufrmRptTest.pas' {frmReport};


{$R *.res}

function RunReport( cmd: PAnsiChar  ):integer;
var  
     frmReport: TfrmReport;
begin
   Application.CreateForm(TDMRPT, DMRPT);   // create datamodule

   Application.CreateForm(TfrmReport, frmReport);  // create form

   try
      frmReport.ShowModal;
   finally
      freeandnil(frmReport);
      freeandnil( DMRpt );
   end;
end;

   Exports
      RunReport name 'RunReport';
end.
```

Environment:

Delphi 11.1
FastReports 2023.1.3 Standard
Delphi 11.1 TeeChart version included with Delphi

I atempted to install the Steema TeeChart VCL/FMX v2023 Standard to see if it resolved the issue. It fails to install on 11.1.

Any suggestions as to how to eliminate the error would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a problem related to using Microsoft GDI+ inside a dll.

You might want to try the following in the caller exe:
https://steema.com/wp/blog/2014/03/12/teechart-and-gdi-inside-a-dll/

or, disabling GDI+ inside the dll, before the charts are created:

TeeDefaultCanvas:='';

regards !
david

Comment: Adding TeeDefaultCanvas := ''; to the form's Formcreate event worked perfectly!   Many thanks!